# Qtablewidget Deleting row issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

Need some expert advice here.

Am using PyQT5 and Python 3 to set up an  UI. I have created a table with Qtablwiwdget and I was able to get most of the controls. However, am stuck in a delete operation. I have created a **Delete** button which deletes the selected row. Am able to achieve this by passing `currentrow` value to the `removerow` function.

Now the issue is that, after every delete, the currentrow count gets decreased by 1 and hence if I click the delete button multiple times, the rows above the selected row is being deleted rather than the ones below.

Here is my code :

```
        self.DataTable = QTableWidget(self)
        self.DataTable.setColumnCount(3)
        self.DataTable.setRowCount(1)
        self.DataTable.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Name","Age","Location"])
        self.DataTable.horizontalHeaderItem(0).setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.DataTable.horizontalHeaderItem(1).setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.DataTable.horizontalHeaderItem(2).setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.DataTable.resize(450, 400)

        self.Delete_butn.clicked.connect(self.On_Delete_Click) # button click
```

#slot

```
@pyqtSlot()
    def On_Delete_Click(self):
        SelectedRow = self.DataTable.currentRow()
        rowcount = self.DataTable.rowCount()

        if rowcount==0:  # gives a pop up when now more rows are there to delete
            msg = QMessageBox(self)
            msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Warning)
            msg.setText("NOTE:")
            msg.setInformativeText("\n No more rows to delete! \t\t")
            msg.setWindowTitle("WARNING!")
            # msg.setDetailedText("The details are as follows:")
            msg.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
            msg.buttonClicked.connect(self.msgbtn)
            retval = msg.exec_()



        elif SelectedRow==-1: # Gives pop up when no rows are selected

            msg = QMessageBox(self)
            msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Warning)
            msg.setText("NOTE:")
            msg.setInformativeText("\n Please select the row to be deleted! \t\t")
            msg.setWindowTitle("WARNING!")
            # msg.setDetailedText("The details are as follows:")
            msg.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
            msg.buttonClicked.connect(self.msgbtn)
            retval = msg.exec_()


        else:
            self.DataTable.removeRow(SelectedRow)
```

What i want to achieve is that, if am having 8 rows (from 0-7) having correct values and at rows 3-6 having wrong values, I'll be clicking row 3 first, click delete . On deleting , the row shifts up and I should be deleting row 3 again . But its not happening. After 1st delete operation, current row is decreasing from 3 to 2 as a result am losing values on that was present on top of the wrong valued cells

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the row associated with the currentIndex() decreases by 1 after deleting the row that is the same as currentRow(), so the solution is to establish that the currentIndex has the same location after removing the row:

```
# ...
else:        
    self.DataTable.removeRow(SelectedRow)
    ix = self.DataTable.model().index(
        SelectedRow, self.DataTable.currentColumn()
    )
    self.DataTable.setCurrentIndex(ix)
# ...
```

Comment: Thanks. Its working. Meanwhile, when I was searching around I found `selectrows` function and it give me an easy fix. I'll put that as an answer as well

Answer (score 0):

Got a simple fix for my problem after stumbling up on  `selectrows` function. Replaced my else condition with the below one

```
    SelectedRow = self.DataTable.currentRow()
    self.DataTable.removeRow(SelectedRow)
    self.DataTable.selectRow(SelectedRow)
```

`self.DataTable.selectRow` makes the **SelectedRow** value same until a new row is selected via a mouse click